# AWS: Best way to automatically create MySQL dump of an RDS instance and store it to S3

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I've researched Lambda however most people are telling me that it isn't the best option for performing automatic RDS backups. Yes I know about the built-in snapshotting system however it doesn't have cross-region support and doesn't interact with S3 at all. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Add a question mark to the end of the title

Comment: Also, personally I've experienced extremely long wait times for restoring an RDS snapshot (clean database, only schemas ~40 min vs mysqldump < 5 min)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy RDS snapshots across regions (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-snapshot-copy-for-amazon-rds/).

If you are just looking for a simple database dump to S3 you can make a cron job to dump the database (like MySQL's `mysqldump`) and upload the created dump to S3 via the AWS CLI.

Comment: Thanks for that link! We're trying to move away from having automation done via cron and bash in general in favor of Jenkins, lambda, and python.

Comment: Are you open to Cron and Python script or you want Lambda and Jenkins mandatory?

Comment: Right now it looks like I'm going to be using Lambda's built-in triggering mechanism to ssh into a server w/ access to the RDS and then execute a python script there which performs the backup and upload to S3.